# how to remove the dotted line around the clicked/focused sap ui5 element

Tags: sapui5

I have been working to remove the dotted lines used to highlight the focused element. But seems I'm not finding any solution.

It's even visible in [SAP UI5 Demo](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.Splitter/methods/Summary) kit.

[Image Highlighting the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Nkh.png)

Could you please suggest a solution.

Thanks,
Samee

Comment: It's feasible but the outline shouldn't just be removed for the sake of the aesthetic since it degrades a11y support (e.g. for keyboard users). I think the outlines are very important but not always. I filed a feature request to display outline only on keyboard interaction: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1289#issuecomment-289203290. But the current a11y standard seems to be to display the outline *always* no matter which input device was used (except of smartphones).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the dotted line you can overwrite this css class:

```
.sapMLIBFocusable:focus {
    outline: 1px dotted #000000;
    outline-offset: -1px;
}
```

i do not recommend overwriting this class directly, but rather add a styleclass to your element, and include that as a selector, like so.

```
.yourclass .sapMLIBFocusable:focus {
    outline: 2px solid red;
    outline-offset: -1px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can overwrite sap css classes like this

```
html.sap-desktop .sapUiBody :focus {
outline: none;}
```

This an example for class *.sapUiBody* but you can use any other sap class or even one of your's.